# Java subprocess built using ProcessBuilder looses data from serial port

Tags: java, linux, serial-port, subprocess, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to read data from the serial port in a subprocess inside a Java application. Here is the code I'm currently using:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Text {
    public static void main(String... arguments) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Process pb = new ProcessBuilder().command("/bin/sh", "-c", "(stty raw; cat) < /dev/ttyAMA0").start();
        final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputStream(pb.getInputStream())));

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                    System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
                }
            }
        });

        t.start();
        pb.waitFor();
    }
}
```

The idea is the following: I wan't to rely on the operating system (here a Raspbian on a Raspberry Pi) to send me raw input from the serial port. I therefore launch a subprocess that sets the serial port to RAW mode using stty, and forward data using cat. This trick works perfectly on the command line. If I then redirect stdout to a Java program, data flows correctly to its input stream.

The problem here is that using this code to get data to a subprocess (not the stdin of the Java programm, you guessed it), I'm loosing characters. I expect lines of 10 numbers of 3 digits, separated by commas, and I get between 4 and 6 numbers, sometimes followed by a comma.

I think there's a buffering issue, my Java application might not be able to empty the (very limited) serial port buffer.

Is there something I could do Java wise, or should I turn to the Linux kernel geeks for some OS tricks here?

Thanks,

Mathieu

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using a subprocess instead of a serial port library?

Comment: I couldn't find any library that works great, is lightweight, does nothing else, works on a Raspberry Pi, and is not a Jar hell regarding Jar signing (I tried to sign Pi4J, then decided to go my own way) Did I mention I see no reason to use a library for a 5 liner? (ok, not a one-liner...)

Comment: There are at least half a dozen serial port libraries for Java, at least some of which work on a Pi.  And unless you're doing applet coding, you don't need to sign a jar.  If it works, then use whatever.

Comment: Signing is required for JavaFX use. Sorry I didn't asked for it. I know there are dozens of libs available. But I repeat: No one I know is single purpose AND works flawlessly. These 5 lines of code do, so what's the point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got the code working, using input from there: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40005/alternate-fifo-device-for-linux-with-a-way-bigger-buffer-while-still-having-fi

What we want here is a bigger buffer between the (not so many bytes) serial port buffer and the next command in the pipe. Given I expect a 82 bytes line all inclusive, I use the `buffer -s 82 -b 2` command, which allows two blocks of one line to be stored in shared memory between every scanner nextLine call.

Here is the full demo, which should delight every Raspberry Pi owner trying to read serial data in Java (am I the only one?):

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Text2 {
    public static void main(String... arguments) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Process pb = new ProcessBuilder().command("/bin/sh", "-c", "(stty raw; cat | buffer -s 82 -b 2) < /dev/ttyAMA0").start();
        final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputStream(pb.getInputStream())));

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                    System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
                }
            }
        });

        t.start();
        pb.waitFor();
    }
}
```

This expects the `buffer` utility, easily installed typing `sudo apt-get install buffer`
This also relies on some tricks to enable onboard serial port as in https://github.com/lurch/rpi-serial-console

Thanks brettw for the input that led there, even if it didn't work in the first place.

Mathieu

Comment: For those interested in some real world use for this kind of code, I have pushed my (little) project there: https://github.com/mathieubolla/arduino-pi-javafx-dashboard where the serial port is listened to in ThermoduinoService via a SerialPortIterable, where all the magicks occur. Thanks all for your comments that made the thing possible (and reliable)

Answer (score 0):

Try to flush after writing, I guess that this is why you "loose" data :)

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
    System.out.flush();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, this doesn't fix the problem. I loose data in the serial port buffer, which has nothing to do with system out.

Answer (score 0):

Just a hack, but try this.  The stdout from cat is buffered by default, but what you want is an unbuffered stream .  Try to change the line:

```
(stty raw; cat) < /dev/ttyAMA0
```

to

```
(stty raw; cat -u) < /dev/ttyAMA0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this doesn't fix the problem. On the raspbian, `man cat` says the -u option does... Nothing. I tried replacing `cat` by `sed -e ''` which should be a noop (and therefore a buffer), but then I loose all my data. Will try various equivalents to introduce a buffer between cat and my process.

Comment: Ok, I can't answer because I have no reputation here... I have a solution I will post in five hours. It relies on `buffer`, described there: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40005/alternate-fifo-device-for-linux-with-a-way-bigger-buffer-while-still-having-fi